# Do multiple product flavors assets get packaged with ever build variant?

Tags: android, android-productflavors

I have multiple product flavors in my android app where assets(drawables, fonts, colors) are different for each flavor. I was curious that when you generate an apk for one of the build variants, does it also bundle the assets of the other build variants present?

Comment: It should not do that, barring bugs/limitations. If you have evidence indicating that this does happen, post a sample app demonstrating the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not copy the resources/source from other flavours, You can verify that by changing the extension of .apk file to .zip and extracting it!